# Filtering string column with datetime in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, filter, date, datetime

I have a CSV in QGIS and one of the columns is `"Data/Hora GPS"` with the DateTime in format (day/month/year hour:minute:second), in the field calculator I used the expression for filter:

```py
to_datetime("Data/Hora GPS",'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') >
  to_datetime('03/02/2010 14:20:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') and
  to_datetime("Data/Hora GPS",'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') <
  to_datetime('04/02/2010 15:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

But now I want to do this in PyQGIS, How I can do that? (The Data/Hora GPS is a string column)

Comment: Do you want to apply a filter or calculate a new field, or both?

Comment: Just apply a filter

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the filter manually to make sure the syntax is correct. Maybe you should use your locales date format, mine is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Example:

```
"Data/Hora GPS" > '1992-03-05 14:20:00' AND "Data/Hora GPS" < '1992-03-20 15:00:00'
```

then execute the rows

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("randomdates")[0] #Change to the name of your layer
print(layer.subsetString())
"Data/Hora GPS" > '1992-03-05 14:20:00' AND "Data/Hora GPS" < '1992-03-20 15:00:00'
```

To see what the filter string looks like.

Then apply the filter:

```
layer.setSubsetString('') #Clear the filter
filterstring = "\"Data/Hora GPS\" > '1992-03-05 14:20:00' AND \"Data/Hora GPS\" < '1992-03-20 15:00:00'" #You need to escape \" the inner double quotes

layer.setSubsetString(filterstring)
```

Comment: Thanks, it really worked, but I think the filter is reading the date conditions as a string, is that ok? Doesn't this mean that under certain date conditions it ends up not filtering exactly to the date I want because it's being read as a string? I don't know much about programming

Comment: I believe it is the correct syntax for dates and it should work.